# Why is the geometric spread and dispersion spread in a pinhole camera independent?

Tags: optics, camera

About [6:08 of this video](https://youtu.be/n5W3qztO4os?t=365), the equation for geometric spread($ x_{geo}$) is derived for a pinhole camera:
$$ x_{geo} = \frac{d}{s} (f+s) = d(1+ M)$$

Where,

$f$ is focal length

$s$ is subject length

$d$ is diameter of pinhole

$M=\frac{f}{s}$

Around [9:22](https://youtu.be/n5W3qztO4os?t=563) of the same video, he derives the dispersion based spread ($x_{disp}$)as:

$$ x_{disp} =2.44 \frac{\lambda}{d} f$$

Where all common symbols as previous formula have same meaning and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light used and

Now, here come's the interesting part at [10:59](https://youtu.be/n5W3qztO4os?t=659) of the video, he says that both the blurs are additive as in:

$$ x_{blur net} = x_{geo} + x_{disp}$$

Now, afterwards he optimizes the equation with respect to $d$ to figure out what diameter of pinhole would minimize the total blur. However, I do not understand why it must be that the blurs should be additive. Any insight will be appreciated ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for the geometric effects of the pinhole is due to the fact that each point will me mapped to a range of points on the screen $x_{geo}$ as admitted by the pinhole.

The blur is due to diffraction which states that point from the source will be mapped to a "blob" (actually an Airy disc[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk)). The width of this disc is roughly given as you stated.

Tying these two together, each point will be mapped to a distribution with length $x_{disp}$, of Airy discs of width $x_{geo}$ so that the length is the sum of the two - the edges of the geometric range extend a distance $d_{diff}$ to the sides.

A picture may help:

[image]

Comment: Wow! I really look up to your understanding of the topic. Simply amazing.

Comment: A small side questio, in here we had kept a lens in the hole, correct? If we hadn't would we have used the fringe width of regular lens?

Comment: No need for a lens. A circular hole will still map to an Airy disk (in the far field which is to say that $\lambda f \gg r^2$, where $r$ is the hole diameter.) With a circular lens, you also get an Airy disk but of different width. It's confusing because they call $f$ the "focal length" of the pinhole camera, but it's really just the distance to the back plane.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that the geometric blur increases linearly with the pinhole diameter, whereas the diffraction spot size increases *inversely* with the pinhole diameter.  This makes it pretty clear that the effects have independent causes.
Now, when it comes to the total resolution of the image, you're really adding the geometric blur of the light entering at some angle $\theta$ to the diffraction (Airy disc) blur of light entering at some angle $\theta + \phi$  such that the disc from this second light ray just overlaps the image spot from the first light ray.  That's what limits the resolution, or "sharpness" of the image.   I'm not certain but I suspect that's the source of the statement (found on many pages which discuss pinhole cameras) that you can simply add the two blur spot sizes.
By comparison, if you're in a regime where the diffraction spot size is tiny, i.e. large-ish pinhole, then the geometric blur spots of those two entrance angles will overlap already.  So,  the  'best size' pinhole is found when the greater of the two blurs is minimized.  If you minimize  min(x+y) I believe it'll come out the same as min( y|min(x) , x|(min(y) )  .  (That notation means "y when system is at minimum of x"  , etc)

Comment: I'm finding the answer hard to follow at around the second paragraph because I don't understand what you refer to by $ \theta$ and $\phi$

Comment: @Buraian  one ray enters at angle $\theta$ ; the other ray enters at some other angle whose value is  $ \theta + \phi$ for some "small" $\phi$